# Apollo-client self signed certificate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

is there a way that ApolloClient accepts request from servers with self signed certificates?

```
    import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

    const client = new ApolloClient({
        uri: `https://${window.location.hostname}:8080/graphql`,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    });
```

- rejectUnauthorized: false doesn´t work

Error on a Request:
OPTIONS https://localhost:8080/graphql net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Answer (score 3):

**Frontend**

Apollo client might reject the certificate even if you clicked "I understand the risks" and went to the page. You can workaround this by enabling self signed certificates from local host: on chrome type

> chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

to the navigation and click enable.

Other option is to install the certficate as trusted. More about that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate).

**Backend**

If you are using Apollo client in backend with Nodejs you can start the process with:

`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

This can be done with e.g. [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) package.

Comment: doesn work. I've got the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75884056/vue-apollo-client-keeps-getting-self-signed-certificate-error?fbclid=IwAR3leAzS9QU8WboaxzxmYI_2LmBsHbM4VojLNPbOE7ZpN9l59v6YGOhH6Zk

Answer (score 1):

You can also use agent option for development:

```
let fetchOptions = {}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  const https = require('https')
  fetchOptions = { agent: new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false }) }
}
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'https://localhost/api/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
  fetchOptions,
})
```